# Partial derivative command with Deltas in line

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I would like to create a new command for partial derivatives. I have something like this in mind:

```
\newcommand{\deriv}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
```

However, the `\partial` commands are unfortunately not horizontally aligned, if I have e.g something like:

```
\deriv{x^\alpha}{t},
```

i.e. if argument `#1` has a wider horizontal extent as argument `#2`. How can I enforce that the `\partial` commands are always horizontally aligned?

Comment: I am pretty sure, the usual suspects will show up with `esdiff` solutions etc. ;-)

Comment: @egreg I want a horizontal slash, accordingly `/` does not suit well for me.

Comment: Like @JohnKormylo, I suspect that, when you say “in line”, you actually mean “vertically aligned” (like what you would get from, say, `\newcommand*{\deriv}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2\hfill}}`).

Comment: @GuM - You could add another \hfill to the top, just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the numerator and denominator in a box of similar width and ensure they are both `[l]`eft-aligned. This is easily done using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) and automated below to allow for any number of `\deriv`s (using a counter).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcounter{derivcnt}
\newcommand{\deriv}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{derivcnt}%
  \frac
    {\eqmakebox[deriv-\thederivcnt][l]{$\partial #1$}}
    {\eqmakebox[deriv-\thederivcnt][l]{$\partial #2$}}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \deriv{a}{b} + \deriv{abc}{d} - \deriv{a}{bcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Since this approach uses the `.aux` files to store the lengths of the boxes, multiple compilations are required with every change in the `\deriv` content.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [`diffcoeff`](https://ctan.org/pkg/diffcoeff) package. It has many ready to use commands for a variety of differential operators

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\begin{document}
\[ \diff{y}{x}\ \ ,\ \ \diffp[2]{f}{t}\ \ ,\ \ \diffp{f}{x,y} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know this package, but I think it's not correctly made.
For 2nd partial on should use different spacing like
$\partial^2\!f$

Comment: You are right I know what you mean. I don't think it will work like this.